# Netty close/unbind server channel

Tags: netty

I am new to Netty. I am using Netty 4.0.28. I am referring to the the EchoServer example provided in the book "Netty In Action".

Everything is working fine as excepted. Client sends a message to server on channel active, server prints the received message and sends back the same message to client. Later the client channel gets closed but server will be still listening for new connections.

I want to close the server channel as well and want to bind server to a new port.

What should I do to close the server channel?

```
public class EchoServer {

    private final int port;

    public EchoServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                                throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoServerHandler());

                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
            System.out.println(EchoServer.class.getName()
                    + " started and listen on " + f.channel().localAddress());

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: " + EchoServer.class.getSimpleName()
                    + " <port>");
            return;
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        new EchoServer(port).start();
    }
}


@Sharable
public class EchoServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        System.out.println("Server received: " + msg);
        ctx.write(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(
                ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}

public class EchoClient {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public EchoClient(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                                throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoClientHandler());

                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: " + EchoClient.class.getSimpleName()
                    + " <host> <port>");
            return;
        }

        final String host = args[0];
        final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        new EchoClient(host, port).start();;
    }
}

@Sharable
public class EchoClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Netty Rocks!", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Client received: "+ByteBufUtil.hexDump(msg.readBytes(msg.readableBytes())));
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish the "child" channel (which you can get from `ctx.channel()` in your handler, attached to one unique client connection, implicitely refered by the `ctx`) and the "parent" channel (which you can get from `ctx.channel().parent()`).

Closing the "child" will not terminate the `f.channel()` from your main since this one is the "parent" one (the listener). So you have to do something like

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(
            ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
ctx.closeFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                ctx.channel().parent().close();
        }
});
```